# Issues with binding to values in class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've defined a class Root and defined a value(val) in Root's **init**. When I try to bind to val, I get an error "KeyError: 'val'".

I've made an instance root of Root() and tried binding 'val' that way, same error. I also tried defining 'val' from instance root and then binding it

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class Root(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Root).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.val = 1
        self.bind(val=lambda x,y: print(y))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

How do I bind to val successfully and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling `super` wrong, since you have to hand the `self` reference as well.

It should be:

```
super(Root, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Or with Python 3 you can simplify it to:

```
super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through the kivy docs, I realised my mistake. 'val' should be declared before init and with kivy.property

```
class Root(FloatLayout):
    val = NumericProperty(1)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(val=lambda x,y: print(y)) #: Prints 1
```

I should've done more research before posting but regardless, hopefully this helps someone else with the same issue.